# Why can't sphinx-apidoc find the package in this travis/tox build?

Tags: python-3.x, travis-ci, python-sphinx

Travis build: https://travis-ci.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/he/jobs/184044676

conf.py: https://github.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/he/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py

tox.ini: https://github.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/he/blob/master/tox.ini (check out [testenv:doc8])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx cannot find your Python package and import it. Adjust your `sys.path` accordingly:

https://github.com/Laurentiu-Andronache/he/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py#L22

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(__location__, '../../src'))
```

You might need to append `/he` to that value if it does not work.

Comment: Wow, how bad am I at math if I miscalculated the number of ".." required. Thank you, this solved it, and now all the links are verified by `make linkcheck`..