# Extension error during Sphinx document creation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, micropython

I got this error when try to generate my documentation any idea how can I overcome this issue? Thanks!

```
Extension error:
Could not import extension sphinx.builders.linkcheck (exception: No module named 'requests.exceptions'; 'requests' is not a package)
```

I don't know what cause it, but it is coming a from a requests.py file from my repository where is the source code (micropython code base) of the project what I want to document. There is not much here, I just use it cause the built in micropython class produced some bug, so if I can opt it out that is also an option.
it is looks like this

```
try:
    import usocket
except ImportError as e:
    print("Import was unsucsessful, maybe docgeneration triggered? "+str(e))
    import socket

class Response:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.raw = f
        self.encoding = "utf-8"
        self._cached = None

    def close(self):
        if self.raw:
            self.raw.close()
            self.raw = None
        self._cached = None

    @property
    def content(self):
        if self._cached is None:
            try:
                self._cached = self.raw.read()
            finally:
                self.raw.close()
                self.raw = None
        return self._cached

    @property
    def text(self):
        return str(self.content, self.encoding)

    def json(self):
        import ujson
        return ujson.loads(self.content)


def request(method, url, data=None, json=None, headers={}, stream=None):
    try:
        proto, dummy, host, path = url.split("/", 3)
    except ValueError:
        proto, dummy, host = url.split("/", 2)
        path = ""
    if proto == "http:":
        port = 80
    elif proto == "https:":
        import ussl
        port = 443
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported protocol: " + proto)

    if ":" in host:
        host, port = host.split(":", 1)
        port = int(port)

    ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ai = ai[0]

    s = usocket.socket(ai[0], ai[1], ai[2])
    try:
        s.connect(ai[-1])
        if proto == "https:":
            s = ussl.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=host)
        s.write(b"%s /%s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % (method, path))
        if not "Host" in headers:
            s.write(b"Host: %s\r\n" % host)
        # Iterate over keys to avoid tuple alloc
        for k in headers:
            s.write(k)
            s.write(b": ")
            s.write(headers[k])
            s.write(b"\r\n")
        if json is not None:
            assert data is None
            import ujson
            data = ujson.dumps(json)
            s.write(b"Content-Type: application/json\r\n")
        if data:
            s.write(b"Content-Length: %d\r\n" % len(data))
        s.write(b"\r\n")
        if data:
            s.write(data)

        l = s.readline()
        #print(l)
        l = l.split(None, 2)
        status = int(l[1])
        reason = ""
        if len(l) > 2:
            reason = l[2].rstrip()
        while True:
            l = s.readline()
            if not l or l == b"\r\n":
                break
            #print(l)
            if l.startswith(b"Transfer-Encoding:"):
                if b"chunked" in l:
                    raise ValueError("Unsupported " + l)
            elif l.startswith(b"Location:") and not 200 <= status <= 299:
                raise NotImplementedError("Redirects not yet supported")
    except OSError:
        s.close()
        raise

    resp = Response(s)
    resp.status_code = status
    resp.reason = reason
    return resp


def head(url, **kw):
    return request("HEAD", url, **kw)

def get(url, **kw):
    return request("GET", url, **kw)

def post(url, **kw):
    return request("POST", url, **kw)

def put(url, **kw):
    return request("PUT", url, **kw)

def patch(url, **kw):
    return request("PATCH", url, **kw)

def delete(url, **kw):
    return request("DELETE", url, **kw)
    return request("DELETE", url, **kw)
```

Comment: The error message is explicit: "No module named 'requests.exceptions'; 'requests' is not a package". Make it a package and configure `conf.py` so that the package is in its path. Otherwise does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122675/why-cant-sphinx-apidoc-find-the-package-in-this-travis-tox-build/55130316#55130316

Comment: Perhaps there is a name clash between your requests.py and the requests library (https://pypi.org/project/requests/). The linkcheck builder imports requests: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/4.x/sphinx/builders/linkcheck.py#L28

Answer (score 0):

Micropython module "[urequests](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/python-ecosys/urequests/urequests.py)" does not have 'Exceptions' class. Are You trying to use full blown python Sphinx module on Micropython environment? It does not always work that way..

Comment: No ofc I don't.
But when you run sphinx, it run's the python code. And this .py file is imported. That is when the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

another way to resolve this is to :

1. take a copy of the [`cpython_core`](https://github.com/Josverl/micropython-stubs/tree/master/stubs/cpython_core) stubs, and store them somewhere (all-stubs/cpython_core)
2. prepend them to your PYTHONPATH
3. run / debug your MicroPython module in CPython.

for example in VSCODE this looks something like :
`launch.json :`

```json
        {
            "name": "MicroCPython: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                // patch python path with CPYTHON replacements
                "PYTHONPATH": "all-stubs/cpython_core"
            }
        },
```